# Angular - Dynamic FormArray controls not validated

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12 project I have this Dynamic FormArray using Reactive Form.

Component:

```js
updateContact() {
  this.contactInfoForm = this.fb.group({
    id: [''],
    current_residential_address: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(500)]],
    contacts: this.fb.array([
      this.addContactFormGroup()
    ])
  });
}

addContactFormGroup(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    phone_type_id: ['', Validators.required],
    phone_number: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15)]],
    is_primary_contact_number: ['']
  });
}

addContactButtonClick(): void {
  ( < FormArray > this.contactInfoForm.get('contacts')).push(this.addContactFormGroup());
}

get fc() {
  return this.contactInfoForm.controls;
};

contactValidate() {
  if (!this.contactInfoForm.valid) {
    this.contactInfoForm.markAllAsTouched();
    return;
  }
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.updateContact();
  this.loadAllParameters();
}

loadAllParameters() {
  this.employeeService.getEmployeeParameters().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.phonetypes = data.results.phonetypes;
    }
  );
}
```

HTML:

```html
<form [formGroup]="contactInfoForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="current_residential_address">Current Residential Address:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
        <textarea rows="2" formControlName="current_residential_address" name="description" type="text" placeholder="22, Alexander Close ..." class="form-control mb-3" required>
                              </textarea>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="fc.current_residential_address.touched && fc.current_residential_address.invalid">
        <div *ngIf="fc.current_residential_address.hasError('required')">
          <div class="text-danger">
            Current Residential Address is required!
          </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="fc.current_residential_address.hasError('minlength')">
          <div class="text-danger">
            Current Residential Address cannot be less than 2 characters!
          </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="fc.current_residential_address.hasError('maxlength')">
          <div class="text-danger">
            Current Residential Address cannot be more than 500 characters!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div formArrayName="contacts" class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let contact of contactInfoForm.get('contacts').controls">
      <div formGroupName="0" class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone_number">Phone Number:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <div class="input-group mb-4">
              <ngx-intl-tel-input [cssClass]="'form-control mb-4'" [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries" [enableAutoCountrySelect]="false" [enablePlaceholder]="true" [searchCountryFlag]="true" [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Iso2, SearchCountryField.Name]"
                [selectFirstCountry]="false" [selectedCountryISO]="CountryISO.Nigeria" [phoneValidation]="true" [separateDialCode]="true" name="phone_number" formControlName="phone_number">
              </ngx-intl-tel-input>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="fc.phone_number.touched && fc.phone_number.invalid">
            <div *ngIf="fc.phone_number.hasError('required')">
              <div class="text-danger">
                Phone Number is required!
              </div>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="fc.phone_number.hasError('validatePhoneNumber')">
              <div class="text-danger">
                Invalid Phone Number!
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone_type_id">Phone Type:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <ng-select [items]="phonetypes" [selectOnTab]="true" [searchable]="true" bindValue="id" bindLabel="type_name" placeholder="Select Phone Type" [multiple]="false" [clearable]="true" required formControlName="phone_type_id">
            </ng-select>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="fc.phone_type_id.touched && fc.phone_type_id.invalid">
            <div *ngIf="fc.phone_type_id.hasError('required')">
              <div class="text-danger">
                Phone Type is required!
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone_type_id">Is Primary Line?:</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck2">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i> Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" (click)="addContactButtonClick()"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add item</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="isLoading" class="btn btn-success" (click)="contactValidate()">
                      <span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                      <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Only current_residential_address was validated which is not part of the formarray.

But the FormArray (phone_type_id, phone_number) controls were not validated.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get `Phone Number is required!`...No you won't get. None validation will work under `addContactFormGroup`

Comment: @NavnathJadhav - No I didn't get it. What do I do?

Comment: I'm posting answer in full explain

Comment: @NavnathJadhav - I didn't get any validation at all for the formArray.

Comment: I'm surprised you did not get any errors. As soon I added your code in https://stackblitz.com/ I got an error regarding validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `contacts` is an Array of `formGroup`. Let's start with changing the below line

```
<div formArrayName="contacts" class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let contact of contactInfoForm.get('contacts').controls">
      <div formGroupName="0" class="row">
      ...
      </div>
</div>
```

To

```
<div formArrayName="contacts" class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let contact of contacts.controls; let i = index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i" class="row">
       ...
       </div>
 </div>
```

In TS file add a getter to get contact:

```
get contacts() {
    return this.contactInfoForm.controls['contacts'] as FormArray;
}
```

Take a look at your `fc` getter. Its returning `contactInfoForm` controls, which includes `current_residential_address` and `contact` FormArray.

```
get fc() {
    return this.contactInfoForm.controls;
  }
```

Your validation code. Its finding `phone_number` in `fc` which of course it will not find. We need to tell him to find it in `contact` FormArray and by providing `formGroup` index

```
fc.phone_number.touched && fc.phone_number.invalid
```

FormGroup index is available in `let i = index`,
Now, we need a method that takes in the index and returns us `FormGroup` from `contact` `FormArray`.

```
getFormGroup(index: number): FormGroup {
  return this.contacts.at(index) as FormGroup;
}
```

And now to access validation objects:

```
<div *ngIf="getFormGroup(i).get('phone_number').hasError('required')">
 ....
</div>

<div *ngIf="getFormGroup(i).get('phone_type_id').hasError('required')">
 .....
</div>
```

In the demo, I have added to check vali/invalid form

```
{{ "Is Form Valid : "+contactInfoForm.valid}}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xparyb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Let me know if anything missing.

Comment: Thank for your effort. Everything was going fine except for the fact that it underlines hasError('required') and touched and displays this error:  object is possiblu 'null'.   How do I get out of that?

Comment: @user11352561 Try using `!` non-null assertion operator as  
 `getFormGroup(i).get('phone_number')!.hasError('required')`

Answer (score 0):

You are not dynamically assigning the DOM content to the specific index of your `FormArray` you iterate over.

```
<div formArrayName="contacts" class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let contact of contactInfoForm.get('contacts').controls; let i = index;">
      <div [formGroupName]="i" class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So instead of `<div formGroupName="0" class="row">` set it dynamically to use the correct index.